# How to "Group by" with multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables.

```
 1. Users (id,name,createdAt)

 2. Images (id,createdAt)
```

I want to generate a report something like this

```
date       | newUsers | newImages
2019-09-12 | 12       | 3
2019-09-13 | 15       | 5
2019-09-14 | 16       | 8
```

What I've done upto now is

```
SELECT 
    u.newUsers,
    i.newImages
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS newUsers,createdAt
    FROM
        users group by date(createdAt)) u
        left join
        (select count(*) as newImages,createdAt from images group by date(createdAt)) i
```

This has a syntax error unfortunately.

How do I `achieve` this using `mysql`?
Also I am using `Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` on what? Also, provide sample data and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missing `on` clause

```
   select 
        u.newUsers,
        i.newImages,
        u.createdAt
    from
        (select
            count(*) AS newUsers
            , date(createdAt) as createdAt
        from
            users 
        group by date(createdAt)) u
    left join
         (select count(*) as newImages
             , date(createdAt) as createdAt
        from images 
        group by date(createdAt)) i
    on i.createdAt = u.createdAt
```

Comment: Hi, how do I group by the createdAt date?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way -

```
SELECT u.createdAt,COUNT(*) AS newUsers,count(*) as newImages
FROM users u left join images i on u.createdAt=i.createdAt
left join 
group by u.createdAt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that you don't miss any dates, then `left join` is not sufficient.  One method is `union all`/`group by`:

```
select date, sum(is_user) as num_users, sum(is_image) as num_images
from ((select date(createdat) as date, 1 as is_user, 0 as is_image
       from users
      ) union all
      (select date(createdat) as date, 0 as is_user, 1 as is_image
       from images
      ) 
     ) ui
group by date;
```